# In Civ V, playing as Germany, and with earth, how do I start in Europe where Germany should be?

Tags: civilization-5

Every time I start Civ V with Germany and with earth as the terrain, it doesn't start me in central Europe where modern day Germany is. Can I correct this somehow? Civ 4 would automatically start the chosen civilization where it is (or would be) located on earth.

Comment: What it's doing is putting Germany where it first started BEFORE modern day map changes.

Comment: @Retrosaur Really! Where does it put "Germany"? I mean, it didn't even exist as a state until recently, and its best-fit predecessor state didn't exist until after the fall of Rome.

Answer (score 6):

Currently there is no way in the base game to place your civ in it's actual geographical location. However, if you are willing to use them, there is a mod in the steam workshop called "[Yet (not) Another Earth Maps Pack](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=77138438&searchtext=)" by Gedemon that has true starting location as well as a few other features.